# Curl is not supporting SSL (./configure --with-ssl)

Tags: compiling, opensuse, curl, openssl, ssl

I am trying to install curl in opensuse Leap 15.0. I have downloaded the `.zip` file from [this link](https://github.com/curl/curl/releases) (version 7.63.0)

I am running this command from the curl root directory:

```
./configure --with-ssl=/usr/lib
```

which is having the libssl.so.1.1

But the Curl is not displaying the SSL support option.

Any suggestions on which file needs to be added or point to in order to let curl enable the SSL?

Comment: you need the development library of what is required. It ends in `.so` not in `.so.x.y` (like `.so.1.1`). I could not find how to do this on opensuse

Comment: On which operating system are you working/ have worked? If I can get any hint from that, that'd be great help

Comment: it's generic to most *nix. On Debian you just install the additional -dev package to have the required "missing" part

Comment: Do you need to build `curl` from source? I guess there should be a software package ready for opensuse.

Comment: I did try this suggestion. Installed openssl again checked that libssl.so* are in `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib64`  checked for both paths in `--with-ssl` command. No luck. Am I writing the command correct?

Comment: *Any suggestions on which file needs to be added or point to in order to let curl enable the SSL?* - Install from your package manager...

Comment: I checked my system for all the *ssl.so*. fond 3 different versions of openssl in `/usr/lib` and '/usr/local/lib64`. removed all. and then installed openssl from source and then curl `--with-ssl=/usr/local/lib64`. It worked